# How to bind entry from page with ViewModel

Tags: xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms, binding

I'm trying to implement Login system like this:

```
public Command LoginCommand => new Command(async () =>
        {
            LoginModel model = new LoginModel("dnetTest", "dnetTest"); // (get value from entry instead of "dnetTest")

        if (model.CheckInformation())
        {
            bool isSuccess = await LoginService.Login(model);
            if (isSuccess)
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Пријављивање", "Успешно сте се пријавили", "OK.");
                Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();
            }
        }
```

My LogingPage also have:

```
 <Label Text="Korisničko ime"/>
 <Entry x:Name="Entry_Username" Placeholder="Korisničko ime"/>
 <Label Text="Lozinka"/>
 <Entry x:Name="Entry_Password" Placeholder="Lozinka"/>
 <Button Text="Prijavi se" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"/>
```

So, my question is how to bind Entry_Username and Entry_Password with LoginModel in LoginViewModel?
And is there any way to bind it without using x:Names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be fair; this is a very basic MVVM question that is easy to find, of which the solution is in multiple blogs and pages. But, let me help you get started.

> And is there any way to bind it without using x:Names?

The whole point of data binding is that you do not have to make any hard references to these controls. We want to separate the logic from the UI so that we can easily replace one or both without having to touch the other. For instance, say that you want to implement a new design, if you use data binding, you can just show the current properties in the view model (or page model as it is referred to in the Xamarin space as well) if you reference those in your new UI.

If you would have all kind of `x:Name` references, you would not only have to touch your UI, but also the view model and go through all the references to those fields and replace them as well.

Using data binding promotes reusability and testability mostly.

As for your specific case. I can't see your full code, so there will be some assumptions made here. First, I'm going to assume that your `LoginCommand` lives in a view model of its own right now. You are already using data binding there, which is good. I don't directly see why you would need a separate model for the view model and the login, possibly your `LoginModel` is more like a service. Also, I'm assuming you're doing this manually, without the help of an MVVM framework. It's good to know what happens under the hood, but I would recommend looking at using an MVVM framework like FreshMvvm or Prism for example.

The login page that holds your XAML, I will call `LoginPage.xaml` which should have a `LoginPage.xaml.cs` code-behind file. In there, go into the constructor and specify this line:

```
public LoginPage()
{
    InitializeComponents();

    // This line is relevant here
    BindingContext = new LoginViewModel();
}
```

Seeing that your `LoginCommand` is already using data binding, this is probably here already.

Now, in your `LoginPage.xaml`, change your XAML to this:

```
 <Label Text="Korisničko ime"/>
 <Entry Text="{Binding Username}" Placeholder="Korisničko ime"/>
 <Label Text="Lozinka"/>
 <Entry Text="{Binding Password}" Placeholder="Lozinka"/>
 <Button Text="Prijavi se" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"/>
```

Notice how I removed the `x:Name` attributes and added the `Text` attributes on the two `Entry` controls.

Next, go into your `LoginViewModel.cs` and add two properties, like this:

```
public string Username { get; set; }
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Whenever the text changes in your `Entry` controls, these properties should contain the value accordingly. Now, you can change the code you posted to something like this:

```
public Command LoginCommand => new Command(async () =>
{
    // Notice how I changed this line
    LoginModel model = new LoginModel(Username, Password);

    if (model.CheckInformation())
    {
        bool isSuccess = await LoginService.Login(model);
        if (isSuccess)
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Пријављивање", "Успешно сте се пријавили", "OK.");
            Application.Current.MainPage = new MainPage();
        }
    }
```

This should work for you!

As mentioned, I would recommend looking further into MVVM as a whole and also MVVM frameworks. Here is the [official Docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm), [a good writeup](https://xamarinhelp.com/use-xamarin-forms-mvvm-framework/) by Adam Pedley and something [I wrote myself](https://blog.verslu.is/xamarin/xamarin-forms-xamarin/beauty-and-the-beast-use-mvvm-to-unleash-inner-beauty/) a while back.

Comment: Thank's it's working.
The whole problem was in 
`public string Username { get; set; }
public string Password { get; set; }`
Because I defined it in LoginModel.cs, not in LoginViewModel.

Comment: Great! Yes, the data binding engine looks for properties in the object defined in the `BindingContext` property of your page